# Plotting subsetted Pandas data frame using ipywidgets

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, ipywidgets

I would like to plot subsets of a `pandas` data frame, using dropdown menus from `ipywidgets`, and I am getting some strange errors.

```
import ipywidgets as wg
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make Data Frame
#
df = pd.DataFrame({
    
    "x": np.arange(32),
    "y": np.arange(32),
    "A": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    "B": [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    "C": [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
})

# Make dropdown menus
#
w1 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=[0,1],
    value=0,
    description='A:',
)
#
w2 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=[0,1],
    value=0,
    description='B:',
)
#
w3 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=[0,1],
    value=0,
    description='C:',
)
#
w4 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=['df'],
    value='df',
    description='DF:',
)

# Define plotting function
#
def myPlot(df, a, b, c):
    print(df)
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
    x = df["x"][df["A"]==a & df["B"]==b & df["C"]==c]
    y = df["y"][df["A"]==a & df["B"]==b & df["C"]==c]   
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.show()

# Plot with interactive dropdown menus
#
wg.interact(myPlot, df=w4, a=w1, b=w2, c=w3)
```

The error happens when I try to define `x` in the plotting function: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. I think it has to do with getting the data frame into the plotting function, because the `print` commands in the plotting function give me the right values of `A`, `B`, and `C` but prints the string `df`.

What would be the way to get the plots that I want?

Comment: you're trying to extract variables from the name space with strings. I don't recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to extract variables from the namespace with strings.

I would wrap your interactor and pass the dataframe directly:

```py
import ipywidgets as wg
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Make Data Frame
#
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": np.arange(32),
    "y": np.arange(32),
    "A": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    "B": [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    "C": [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
})

# Make dropdown menus
#
w1 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=[0,1],
    value=0,
    description='A:',
)
#
w2 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=[0,1],
    value=0,
    description='B:',
)
#
w3 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=[0,1],
    value=0,
    description='C:',
)


# Define plotting function
#
def myPlot(df, a, b, c):
    subset = df.loc[df["A"].eq(a) & df["B"].eq(b) & df["C"].eq(c), :]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter("x", "y", data=subset)
    return fig


def interactive_plotter(df):
    df_widget = wg.fixed(df)
    return wg.interact(myPlot, df=df_widget, a=w1, b=w2, c=w3)

fig = interactive_plotter(df)
```

Another thing is to consider is your chained logic statements:

The order of operations with logic operators isn't really intuitive

This statement:

```py
x = df["x"][df["A"]==a & df["B"]==b & df["C"]==c]
```

Is evaluated as:

```py
x = df["x"][df["A"] == (a & df["B"]) == (b & df["C"]==c)]
```

(or something close to that).

What you want, at a bare minimum, is this:

```py
x = df["x"][(df["A"] == a) & (df["B"] == b) & (df["C"] == c)]
```

But I think it'd be better to use the `.loc` accessor:

```py
x = df.loc[(df["A"] == a) & (df["B"] == b) & (df["C"] == c), "x"]
```

If you don't like all those parentheses, you can also use `.eq()`

```py
x = df.loc[df["A"].eq(a) & df["B"].eq(b) & df["C"].eq(c), "x"]
```

Comment: I think this got me what I wanted, thanks! What does the `.eq` do, though?

Comment: @Dave https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to switch between different dataframes to plot, put them in a dictionary, give each one a unique string key, and then pass that Dictionary as the options to the Dropdown.

```py
import ipywidgets as wg
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make Data Frame
#
df = pd.DataFrame({
    
    "x": np.arange(32),
    "y": np.arange(32),
    "A": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    "B": [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    "C": [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
})

choices = {
    'df': df
}

# Make dropdown menus
#
w1 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=[0,1],
    value=0,
    description='A:',
)
#
w2 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=[0,1],
    value=0,
    description='B:',
)
#
w3 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=[0,1],
    value=0,
    description='C:',
)
#
w4 = wg.Dropdown(
    options=['df'],
    value='df',
    description='DF:',
)

# Define plotting function
#
def myPlot(df_name, a, b, c):
    df = choices[df_name]
    x = df.loc[(df["A"]==a) & (df["B"]==b) & (df["C"]==c)]["x"]
    y = df.loc[(df["A"]==a) & (df["B"]==b) & (df["C"]==c)]["y"]  
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.show()

# Plot with interactive dropdown menus
#
wg.interact(myPlot, df_name=w4, a=w1, b=w2, c=w3)
```

PS. Also your indexing calls for your DataFrame are the wrong order. 1) Filter the rows, then 2) select the column you want.

```py
df.loc[(df["A"]==a) & (df["B"]==b) & (df["C"]==c)]["x"] # correct order

df['x'].loc[(df["A"]==a) & (df["B"]==b) & (df["C"]==c)] # incorrect order
```