# Slicing dataframes using ipywidgets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, ipywidgets

I am trying to create an interactive plot using IPywidgets and Plotly.

I have created and defined the plotly.go output that I would like as a method, and have validated this works using text variables, but I am now looking to define the inputs using IPywidgets.

The buttons have been defined and show up as expected, but the output underneath returns an error for the Plotly graph : *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'*

The error points to the first line of the method, where I use an unput to create a slice from the DataFrame. Should I take this to mean that the DataFrame is being parsed(?) as a string file rather than as a DataFrame? How do I fix this?

I won't post all the code as it is quite long (unless deemed neccessary), but have summarised it below:

Code used to create the interactive plot:

```
# define a list of analytes to be used for the button
analyte_list = df['ANALYTE'].unique()
first_value = analyte_list[1]

# define buttons to be used on blank plots
sort_options = widgets.ToggleButtons(options = ['HOLEID', 'SAMPLEID'], description = "Sort Samples By:", disabled = False,
    button_style = "success")
analyte_options = widgets.Dropdown(options = analyte_list, value = first_value,   description = 'Analyte', disabled = False)
detection_limits_select = widgets.FloatText(value = 10, description = 'Detection Limits:', disabled = False)

widgets.interact(blank_plots, df = df, element = 'Ce', sort_by = sort_options, dl = detection_limits_select)
```

Code at the beginning of the method that is causing issues:

```
def blank_plots(sort_by, element, dl, df = pd.DataFrame):

    # create dataframe for selected analyte
    #dfa = df[df['ANALYTE']==e].copy()
    dfa = df.loc[df["ANALYTE"]==element].copy()
```

And the error output:

```
     16     # create dataframe for selected analyte
     17     #dfa = df[df['ANALYTE']==e].copy()
---> 18     dfa = df.loc[df["ANALYTE"]==element].copy()
     20     # define units
     21     units = dfa['UNIT'].unique().tolist()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Any advice welcomed, and I will answer any questions I can.

Comment: Could you please show me how you call `def blank_plots(sort_by, element, dl, df = pd.DataFrame)` in your code?

Comment: it is called through the "widgets.interact(..." line at the base of the 1st code block

Comment: try to print this before widget.interact print(type(df))

Comment: Prints class as: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: Please add all the code to debug it easily.

Comment: I have found a solution using the example in the link below. Thanks for trying though.

As I thought, the widget wrapper was converting the dataframe to a different Type, but that has been fixed using a static widget.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707184/plotting-subsetted-pandas-data-frame-using-ipywidgets

Comment: Please as this as a solution for your question for future comers.